# Rueppel's example of self-clocking LFSR

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

Consider the following excerpt from Rueppels paper, titled [When Shift Registers Clock Themselves](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-39118-5_6):

> [image: Excerpt from Rueppel's paper]

His example includes $C(D) = 1 + D + D^2 + D^3 + D^4 + D^5$ as a **primitive** connection polynomial. However, this polynomial is not irreducible, let alone primitive, since it can be factored as $(1+D)(1+D+D^2)^2$ over $\text{GF}(2)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your question regarding the hardware or just the mathematics.  You would be required to have 5 flip-flops, whether or not it is irreducible.  The single vs. double clocking is interesting as it effectively behaves as adding some logic between blocks.

Comment: @bdegnan I've come to this question, dunno why, It took 15 minutes to code -with a library- to see the error in the article.

Comment: @kelalaka I really have no idea how you found this again. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the article. The primitive polynomial must be $$x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$$

---

The easiest way to see that there is a mistake or not is coding!

There is an almost good [pylfsr](https://pypi.org/project/pylfsr/) library. This library also lists primitive polynomials in their format.

`L.get_fpolyList(m=5)`

- [5, 2]
- [5, 4, 2, 1]
- [5, 4, 3, 2]

[The list verified](https://www.partow.net/programming/polynomials/index.html#deg05), too.

- $x^5 + x^2 + 1$
- $x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x^1 + 1$
- $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$

I've created a python program to test these. Luckily I've found it on the first try!

```
import numpy as np
from pylfsr import LFSR

state = [1,1,1,1,1]
fpoly = [5, 4, 3, 2]
L = LFSR(fpoly=fpoly,initstate =state, verbose=False)
L.info()

for i in range(1,21):
    print(L.state[-1], end=",")
    if L.outbit == 0:
        L.next()
    else :
        L.next()
        L.next()
print("\n")
print("1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1")
```

It produces the output

```
5 bit LFSR with feedback polynomial  x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1
Expected Period (if polynomial is primitive) =  31
Current :
 State        :  [1 1 1 1 1]
 Count        :  0
 Output bit   :  -1
 feedback bit :  -1
 1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,

 1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
```

Thanks to [Nikesh Bajaj](https://github.com/Nikeshbajaj/Linear_Feedback_Shift_Register/issues/4) to indicate better usage of the library ( See in the other library).

Therefore there is a typo in the article. The primitive polynomial must be $$x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to WHY -1?** [**Updates: Fixed pylfsr**]

The output of LFSR is indeed the last bit of intial state, but there is no output bit, if no clock cycle (L.next()) is excuted. -1 has been intentionally used to show that LSFR has not been passed any clock.

The print line should be at end not in start.

```
import numpy as np
from pylfsr import LFSR

state = [1,1,1,1,1]
fpoly = [5, 4, 3, 2]
L = LFSR(fpoly=fpoly,initstate =state, verbose=False)
L.info()

for i in range(1,21):
    if L.outbit == 0:
        L.next()
    else :
        L.next()
        L.next()
    print(L.outbit, end=",")
print("\n")
print("1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1")
```

Output:

```
5 bit LFSR with feedback polynomial  x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1
Expected Period (if polynomial is primitive) =  31
Current :
 State        :  [1 1 1 1 1]
 Count        :  0
 Output bit   :  -1
 feedback bit :  -1
1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,

1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
```

Due to clock consideration, this is a shifted version of the output sequence. An alternative code to produce exact response is here

```
state = [1,1,1,1,1]
fpoly = [5, 4, 3, 2]
L = LFSR(fpoly=fpoly,initstate =state, verbose=False)
L.info()

for i in range(1,21):
    print(L.state[-1], end=",")
    if L.outbit == 0:
        L.next()
    else :
        L.next()
        L.next()
    #
print("\n")
print("1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1")
```

which produces:

```
5 bit LFSR with feedback polynomial  x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1
Expected Period (if polynomial is primitive) =  31
Current :
 State        :  [1 1 1 1 1]
 Count        :  0
 Output bit   :  -1
 feedback bit :  -1
1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,

1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks @kelalaka for pointing out. I have fixed the issue in updated version=1.0.5 of [pylfsr](https://pypi.org/project/pylfsr/1.0.5/), with an additional parameter ***counter_start_zero***, which initialize the output bit with -1, untill first clock is passed. So your original code produces the expected answer by either setting ***counter_start_zero=False*** or executing L.next() before checking the first output. See [here detail](https://github.com/Nikeshbajaj/Linear_Feedback_Shift_Register/issues/4#issuecomment-823883124)

So yes, there is a typo in the article, x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1 is correct primitive polynomial, which can also be verfying by three properties (1) balance (2) runlength (3) autocorrelation